# Exclude duplicate rows while aggregating one column based on distinct values in another using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, distinct

Given the table employees, I need to write a query to obtain total salary for each department. Any duplicate e_id in the table must not be counted twice (in this case Molly).

The table looks like this:

(Please pardon my way of inserting data table, I am new to posting questions on SO)

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg .tg-0pky{border-color:inherit;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-0lax{text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-0pky">e_id</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">l_name</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">f_name</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">salary</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">dept_id</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">12</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">grace</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Barbara</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">8400</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">34</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Gates</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">David</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">8000</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">39</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Patrick</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Neil</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">7500</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">45</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Park</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Molly</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">8100</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">45</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Park</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Molly</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">8100</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">75</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Gates</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Ryan</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">8300</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The output desired is:

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg .tg-s268{text-align:left}
.tg .tg-0lax{text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-s268">Uniq_Dept</th>
    <th class="tg-s268">TotalSalary</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-s268">1</td>
    <td class="tg-s268">23900</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">2</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">16400</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `distinct` in a subquery to remove duplicates row by `dept_id` then do `SUM`

**Query #1**

```
SELECT dept_id as Uniq_Dept,SUM(salary) as TotalSalary 
FROM (
  SELECT distinct dept_id, salary
  FROM t 
) t1
GROUP BY dept_id;

| Uniq_Dept | TotalSalary |
| --------- | ----------- |
| 1         | 23900       |
| 2         | 16400       |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/atkcaRfZ5ZY9X6o6kuNZTk/0)

Comment: @SoniG What do you mean `distinct` exclude the duplicate row

Comment: "The query above prints out unique salary values. Also, it is adding up the duplicated row instead of excluding it." if that is the case then your expected output also is properly wrong.. @SoniG because the result from this query and your expected result are the same.

Comment: Apologies @D-Shih, my comment was to the first query you posted. Later I realised the edits and tried it out and it worked.. Thank you once again!

Comment: "my comment was to the first query you posted. Later I realised the edits" @SoniG D-Shih never changed the query https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52582498/revisions

Comment: @RaymondNijland, The first query posted was Edited/Deleted. it was-

SELECT dept_id as Uniq_Dept,SUM(salary) as TotalSalary
FROM t
GROUP BY e_id,dept_id; 

To which I commented stating it didn't produce the desired result.

Anyway, I am pretty new to using SO and I don't mean to offend anyone by being naive. Apologies for any mistakes from my end and definitely appreciate the help!

Comment: "The first query posted was Edited/Deleted" i geuss the first post was deleted then i never saw/readed it.. "I don't mean to offend anyone by being naive. Apologies for any mistakes from my end and definitely appreciate the help" No worries now you explained @SoniG